# Tried deploying with Firebase and Github Pages and both pages were blank

Tags: firebase, deployment, github-pages

This is my first time trying to deploy a react app so please bear with me.

I created an amazon-clone and tried deploying with firebase.

I clicked on the link and it was a white page. Inspecting showed the page loaded index.html from my build folder. I tried with Github pages and same problem.

In the console, I have several "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" errors.

When I run npm start the page shows locally without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally solved the problem with Firebase. I followed the steps on this page: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/.
I also checked the "homepage" in package.json from my GitHub repository to the firebase link I was deploying to.
The problem remains with GitHub pages though.